# Socket.io not generating unique socket ID per connection on Heroku

Tags: node.js, react-native, heroku, socket.io

Heroku back logs are showing the same amount of user connected even with two different devices.

However, localhost is working fine. Each time a device connects, a new socket is generated. This is not the case on Heroku.

[image: Heroku Logs]

So its connecting fine, but that connection is the same across two different devices?

Answer (score 0):

I had the server clustered. Removing that fixed the issue.
Looks like Socket.io requires additional configuration if you're going to cluster node.